# How to avoid from having more than 1 duplicates foreign key in a continuous form?

Tags: database, vba, duplicates

I have made items sub form (continuous form) in access, where multiple products are added. I have been searching for hours to find a way to restrict a repetition  of item. ie. 
[image]

In this scenario, stock id is repeated for second time so is there a way i can  restrict this from happeneing.

Comment: How do you populate the source of the combo? Query or hardcoded values?

Comment: I have made a vba function that is mixed up of vba and sql

Comment: Can you post how you populate the combo's rowsource?